# Find matrix of derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, curves

A robot traverses a path γ : [0,1] -> R^2 given by γ(t)=(t  sin⁡((π/2)t)) (sorry this is a 2x1 matrix).

First, explain why the robot remains on the plate. Then write down the matrix γ' of the derivative of γ at general t ∈ (0,1).

Not really sure where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean 
$$
\gamma(t)=(t,\sin (\pi/2 t))
$$
in which case you find the derivative of the curve component-wise
$$
\gamma'(t)=(1,\pi/2\cos (\pi/2 t))
$$

Comment: its sin((pi/2)(t)). So pi over 2 times t